# Tensorflow 2.0 CNN training: Image augmentation function shifts pixel values outside of the [0, 1] range. Is this a problem?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, data-augmentation

I am working on my specific data augmentation function to train a **CNN** in **TensorFlow 2.0**. The image data I'm using are stored in a `numpy` multidimensional RGB array; all its pixel values are floats in the [0, 1] range.

While playing with function `tensorflow.image.random_brightness` ([documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/image/random_brightness)) I found that its pixel values are shifted outside of the [0, 1] range (etiher above or below). When I try to visualise them using `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()` I get the following message:

> Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data
>   ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers).

I also found that when I try to re-normalize the data in that range, the image comes back to its original look (making the whole process useless).

Are pixel values outside of the [0, 1] range a problem for CNN training? And if this represents a problem, what can I do to have pixel values in the correct range, without giving up adjusting brightness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is a problem since your representing in 0-1 something that is in 0-255, therefore when you feed a value greater than 1. to your CNN, you are feeding the CNN something that it will never see in a real scenario.

Applying random brightness is OK, but you should take care of the overflow problems using the [`tf.clip_by_value`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/clip_by_value) function:

```
image = tf.clip_by_value(image, clip_value_min=0., clip_value_max=1.)
```

Comment: Do you suggest to put everything in the [0, 255] before using `tf.clip_by_value`? Or is [0, 1] fine?

Comment: Convert the image to float first (values in [0,1]), then apply random brightness + clip in [0,1]